# Is there any way to implode the key and values of an associative array in PHP without using a foreach or other function?

Tags: php, arrays, echo, implode

I have an associative array like this:

```
$myarray = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
```

And I want to show the array keys and values like this:

```
a is 1, b is 2, c is 3
```

I don't want to do this by using print_r or var_dump. And I don't want to use a foreach loop too. I just want to use a short code, I have tried this:

```
echo implode('', $myarray);
```

But that doesn't work too, because I can only display the key or only display the value of the array.

Comment: No. You  have to use a loop or at least a function

Comment: `I don't want to use a foreach loop` Just... why? And no functions? Why? This is silly.

Answer (score 5):

Check this one liner,

```
echo implode(',', array_map(function ($a, $b) { return "$a is $b"; }, 
array_keys($myarray),array_values($myarray)));
```

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays
[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) — Return all the values of an array
[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array
[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) — Join array elements with a string

Working [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7105e3b509a487d04f45fb822ec8cc5740e947fc).

Comment: That's rather over the top isn't it? If it's just a question of being one line `foreach($myarray as $key => $value) { echo "$a is $b";}` is shorter, and simpler.

Comment: I agree with you. But he didn't mention short or long. Specifically *No For/Foreach* loop. So I did that. :)

Comment: May I know, where?

Comment: `without using a foreach or other function?` right there in the title.

Comment: Oh Yes, title. Okay. I will see another way around. But if OP is happy, its Ok.

Comment: OP also said `I just want to use a short code`.  So short or long is mentioned. It's fine if OP finds the answer helpful (it was a silly question to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**

```
array_walk($myarray,'test_print');
function test_print($value, $key) {
    echo "$key is $value\n";
}
```

Tried and tested [CODE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/25bd6b0441d892bb262018a594d1e9955376b4ec)

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP has so many core functions this can be done in so many different ways, but here is one that I have found to be faster than most others...

```
<?php

$myarray = array ( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3 );

echo str_replace ( array ( '&', '=' ), array ( ', ', ' is ' ), http_build_query ( $myarray ) );

?>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but the problem with this is that it will encode keys and values as if it were a URL, so may not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Using multi join function:

```
<?php
function multi_join(array | string $separator = '', array $array, string $format = '%s %s'): string {
    return join($separator, array_map(
        fn($key, $value): string => sprintf($format, $key, $value),
        array_keys($array),
        array_values($array)
    ));
}

echo multi_join(', ', ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3], '%s is %s');
```